# How do I fix this symfony config.php permission error?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu

I am trying to set up symfony. I am running ubuntu, I have apache2, phpmyadmin and phpstorm installed. I am getting this error under config.php of my project:

> MAJOR PROBLEMS Major problems have been detected and must be fixed
>   before continuing: Change the permissions of either "app/cache/" or
>   "var/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
>   Change the permissions of either "app/logs/" or "var/logs/" directory
>   so that the web server can write into it.
>   so I went to /var

I tried a few things:

1. `sudo thunar` and then changed all the permissions to writeable. This didn't work and the permissions changed right after.
2. I went on this [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-symfony-2-on-an-ubuntu-vps), it says to use certain commands to fix permissions: `sudo chmod 754 /var/cache` and `sudo chmod 754 /var/log` and `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/cache` and `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/log`
   This also did not work
3. I should also note that I have cleared my cache and restarted apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figure it out by your self.

In any case you can read more about it here: [Setting up Permissions / Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions)

Let me know. Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The cache and log are within the app themselves. This did not make much sense to me initially considering that the permissions of the folder they are in (the root, the www folder) had already had all their permissions set appropriately. All I did was set `chmod -R 755` on those folders IN my app.